# Capybara/Cucumber ambiguous match for similar labels

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I have this code in my page

```
  <div>
    <label for="user_password">Heslo</label>
    <br />
    <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="user_password_confirmation">Heslo pro kontrolu</label>
    <br>
    <input id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" size="30" type="password">
  </div>
```

And I would like to use these steps in Cucumber:

```
And I fill in "Heslo" with "NeznameHeslo328"
And I fill in "Heslo pro konrolu" with "NeznameHeslo328"
```

Step definition is simple:

```
When /^I fill in "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/ do |name, text|
  fill_in(name, :with => text)
end
```

BUT
Capybara raises **Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching field "Heslo" (Capybara::Ambiguous)**
 for first step.

When I change name in label with `for="user_password_confirmation"` to "*Hesla pro kontrolu*" (and second step accordingly), everything is OK.

Is there any way to force Capybara to match exact phrase within label? Without using css selectors in scenario.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

In Capybara 2.1 [you can use `:exact` option](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#exactness):

```
fill_in(name, with: 'Heslo', exact: true)
```

This option is set to `false` by default

---

In previous versions of Capybara it's not possible to make an exact string matching. All matching is done using substrings. You can only use another selector type.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've started using. It's working for me so far:

```
Given /^I fill in "([^\"]*)" with "([^\"]*)"$/ do |field_name, text|
  page.find(field_name).set "#{text}"
end
```

Comment: This is usefull when you search by css (field_name). But that is not correct in scenario. I think, scenario should be from user view. And users see "Password confirmation", not "#password_confirmation".